# SQL DELETE LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

My query is:

```
DELETE p,p2,r 
FROM Profiles p
LEFT JOIN Pics p2 ON p.ID=p2.ProfileID
LEFT JOIN Food f ON p.ID=f.ProfileID
WHERE p.ID = 46
```

This query deletes the User's Profile, all pictures in the Pics table and all matching ProfileID in food table.
Which would leave me
ID 47,48 in Profile table
ID 66,67 in Pics table
ID 30,31,32,34 in Food table

But I want it to also delete all the rows where the Pics.ID ProfileID is 46, so Pics.ID 64 and 65. These two IDs to be deleted from the Food table. which would be Food.ID 30 and 32 so left with just:
ID 31, 34 in Food table

Profile Table:

```
ID Gender
46 male
47 female
48 female
```

Pics Table:

```
ID ProfileID Position
64 46        1 
65 46        2
66 47        1
67 48        1
```

Food Table:

```
ID PicID ProfileID
30 64    47
31 66    48
32 65    47
33 67    46
34 67    47
```

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you rephrase it

Comment: Why not just separate `delete` statements? Are you required on doing them at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
DELETE p,p2,f,f2 
FROM Profiles p
LEFT JOIN Pics p2 ON p.ID=p2.ProfileID
LEFT JOIN Food f ON p.ID=f.ProfileID
LEFT JOIN Food f2 ON p2.ID=f2.PicID
WHERE p.ID = 46
```